# mongodb user profile trouble adding inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Iam trying to create a user profile in my mongo db. I already have a basic user registration /session, login/logout system. However I want to add more fields. For instance how would add a 'last name' or 'date of birth' to the below code?

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var Account = require('../models/account');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render('index', { user : req.user });
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
res.render('register', { });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.body);
Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username, firstname: req.body.firstname }) req.body.password, function(err, account) {
    if (err) {
      return res.render("register", {info: "Sorry. That username already exists. Try again."});
    }

passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
        req.session.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
});
});


router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
res.render('login', { user : req.user });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next) {
req.session.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
req.logout();
req.session.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
});

router.get('/ping', function(req, res){
res.status(200).send("pong!");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Account.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Account = new Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
firstname: String
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

**Register.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
.containerhome
h1 Register
.containerhomeborder
br
br
br
br
br
br
br
br
br
br
form(role='form', action="/register",method="post")
  .form-group
      input.form-control(type='text', name="username", placeholder='Enter Username')
  .form-group
      input.form-control(type='text', name="firstname", placeholder='First Name')
  .form-group
    input.form-control(type='password', name="password", placeholder='Password')
  button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
  &nbsp;
  a(href='/')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type="button") Cancel
br
h4= info
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy

// dependencies
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
secret: 'keyboard cat',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', routes);

// passport config
var Account = require('./models/account');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

// mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/passport_local_mongoose_express4');

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
});
});


module.exports = app;
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
  message: err.message,
  error: err
});
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
message: err.message,
error: {}
});
});


module.exports = app;
```

**User.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Account.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Account = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  dob: Date
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

And where you are adding the fields to the new model:

```
// ...
Account.register(new Account({ 
  username :req.body.username, 
  firstname: req.body.firstname,
  lastname: req.body.lastname,
  dob: req.body.dob
}) req.body.password, function(err, account) {
// ...
```

I would highly suggest reading the mongoose documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried that exact thing. however it doesnt populate 'lastname' or 'dob' in my database. everything else works.

Comment: @Ezzer When you say it doesn't populate those two in the database, do you mean that every time you add a new user with those two parameters given in the body, they get added without the 2 extra fields? Do you get an error?